# can we revert change made to SQL Azure API connection?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I am new to Azure.

While editing the SQL API connection, mistakenly I added the wrong username and password for SQL server authentication.
can I revert this change to the previous version?

as I don't know the username and password for the database.

any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*I don't know the username and password for the database*" How exactly did you set up the connection initially if you didn't have the credentials?

Comment: It was setup by the previous developers and it is not visible after creatng the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the workarounds is to change your connection directly from the connector itself.

[image]

While if you are trying to get the credentials from SQL Server, you can reset the password in the overview pane of your SQL Server.

[image]

and to know your username, in the same overview page you can find it under Server admin

[image]